# PostgreSQL: Friends of friends, but my relationship to those friends

Tags: postgresql

I've two tables, **users** and **connections**, and they have these columns:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text
);

CREATE TABLE connections (
    from_id int REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    to_id int REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    status connection_status,
    PRIMARY KEY (from_id, to_id),
    UNIQUE (from_id, to_id)
);
```

And I also have this type:

```
CREATE TYPE connections_status AS ENUM ('accepted', 'pending');
```

The connections table will contain one row for each connection, so if user1 have a connection with user2, it will be one row, but that doesn't mean that user2 have a connection with user1. See it like Instagram or Twitter, where you have followers and you're following people. So if there are one row in the database with user1 as **from_id** and user2 as **to_id** that means that user1 is following user2.

**Question**

I would like to get a users connections, and my relationships to his connections in one query. For example, say that I'm user1 and I want to find all connections (accepted and pending followers and followees) for user2 and what my connections are to user2`s connections, which can be either accepted, pending or null.

Answer (score 0):

see attached query, i joined connections twice with users
1. users.id with connection.from_id, this join will bring all the users the user1 is following with the following status
2. users.id with connection.to_id, this join will bring all the users that follows user1 with the status.

very impotent: if user1 have more then one connection you will revived row for each combination.

if you like to get one row for each user you can use windows functions , lead and lag

```
select user.id as user,
       user.name,
       following.from_id as user_following,
       following.status as status_following,
       followees.from_id as user_followees,
       followees.status as status_followees
from users
left join connections following on users.id=following .from_id
left join connections followees on users.id=followees.from_id
```